# individualMarkersNoKinect does not publish in ar_pose_marker

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, I use ros kinetic and I downloaded the ar-track-alvar module, to read AR codes, and I want to determine how far they are.
I use a usb camera of logitech and I have written the following launch file.

```
<launch>
    <node name="usb_cam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node">
        <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0"/>
    </node>
    <node name="ar_track_alvar" pkg="ar_track_alvar" type="individualMarkersNoKinect" respawn="false" output="screen">
        <param name="marker_size" value="18"/>
        <param name="max_new_marker_error" value="0.08"/>
        <param name="max_track_error" value="0.2"/>
        <param name="camera_image" value="usb_cam/image_raw"/>
        <param name="camera_info"  value="usb_cam/camera_info"/>
        <param name="output_frame" value="head_camera"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

The fact is that I show an image to the camera with an AR code and in the topic ar_pose_marker nothing is published.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279742/individualmarkersnokinect-does-not-publish-in-ar_pose_marker/) by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-01-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:
My launch file:

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:\

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-19**:
I recommend designing your launch file on the example [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/ar_track_alvar/blob/kinetic-devel/ar_track_alvar/launch/pr2_indiv_no_kinect.launch). You have to specify the **cam_image_topic** and **cam_info_topic** names. Or the node doesn't receive any images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi There,

I have set this node up a few times. I think the problem you're having is that your camera doesn't have any calibration information associated with it. This will mean that the **ar_track_alvar** node has no lens model for your camera and therefore cannot determine the pose estimates of the AR tags.

If you have a look at the [camera calibration node](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration) it will guide you through the process of calibrating your camera and getting the camera info messages published alongside the camera images.

When this is setup and working the **ar_track_alvar** node should start working as you expect.

**update** now that your camera calibration information is in the system there are two more things I think you need to check. The frame_id for your camera is still the default **head_camera** there needs to be a TF connection between this frame and the detection frame set in the launch file for **ar_track_alvar** or you can set them to the same frame_id to keep it simple. The other thing to double check is that the camera image and info topic names are set correctly in the launch file too.

You're very close now.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-15**:
I will investigate in this regard, thank you very much.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-15**:
No problem, let us know how you get on.

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:
I have calibrated the camera and it still does not publish ar_pose_marker.
Results after calibration:

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:
miguel@miguel-desktop:~$ rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 11x7 --square 0.03 image:=usb_cam/image_raw camera:=usb_cam
('Waiting for service', '/usb_cam/set_camera_info', '...')
OK
QXcbConnection: Failed to initialize XRandr
Qt: XKEYBOARD extension not present on the X server.

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to create any config

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:
raceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camera_calibration/camera_calibrator.py", line 247, in on_mouse.
if self.do_upload():
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camera_calibration/camera_calibrator.py", line 204, in do_upload

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:
response = self.set_camera_info_service(info)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 435, in **call**

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:
return self.call(*args, **kwds)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 495, in call

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:
service_uri = self._get_service_uri(request)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 463, in _get_service_uri

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:
raise ServiceException("service [%s] unavailable"%self.resolved_name)
rospy.service.ServiceException: service [/usb_cam/set_camera_info] unavailable

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:
***If I run "rostopic echo usb_cam / camera_info" the result is:***

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:
header:
seq: 975
stamp:
secs: 1515791269
nsecs: 604799264
frame_id: "head_camera"
height: 480
width: 640
distortion_model: "plumb_bob"
D: [0.05735496858713088, -0.5268749253600791, -0.00178863581762347, 0.01630569377650278, 0.0]

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:
K: [719.4932215129019, 0.0, 380.8344451914442, 0.0, 723.8834521935598, 279.7711594016876, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
R: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
P: [695.9738159179688, 0.0, 393.3349275889486, 0.0, 0.0, 725.7437744140625, 280.0919628779666, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
binning_x: 0
binning_y: 0

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:
roi:
x_offset: 0
y_offset: 0
height: 0
width: 0
do_rectify: False

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-19**:
Could you please at these comments to your original question. It's almost impossible to follow like this!

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:
I'm sorry I can not include more content in the original question.

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-19**:\